# Initial Response to Webhook from Azure Function App

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, webhooks, azure-logic-apps

I have a HTTP triggered function inside my function app - it is invoked by the webhook connector in Azure Logic Apps. The way webhooks work in Logic Apps is they need the initial response like `"status:200"` which puts the Logic App to sleep and then when the "work" is done the `callbackURL` is invoked and then the Logic App resumes work. My problem is responding with that initial response from my function app.

If you don't respond to the webhook with a status:2** within 2 minutes then the webhook "retries" which starts a new instance of the function app and that is obviously problematic.

So my code looks something like this

```
try 
{ 
     await function1() // this function runs more than 2 minutes
}
catch(err)
{
     context.log(err)
}
finally
{
     await function2() // this function returns to LogicApp via callbackurl
}
```

I have tried adding `context.res = { status:200}` in the try block and have tried creating an individual function that has `context.res = {status:200}` inside, however none of those work.

If my function runs under 2 minutes then obviously the webhook doesn't retry, however when it does take over 2 minutes it fails.

I tried to build based on the "Webhook" design from this article

[Calling Long Running Functions Azure](https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/calling-long-running-functions-from-logic-apps-6d7ba5044701)

These are the combinations I have tried:

```
try {
    context.bindings.res = {status:202}
    await function1()
}

try {
    context.res = {status:202}
    await function1()
}

try {
    await initialResponse(context)// function that has context.res={status:202} inside
    function1()
}

try {
    context.res = {status:202}
    context.done()
    await function1()
} // I added @UncleDave 's suggestion as well

try {
    await initialResponse(context)
    function1()
}
async function initialResponse(context)
{
    context.res = {status:202}
    context.done()
} // this attempt also just ended the function
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a second function to handle the long running operation and change your current function to throw the request on to a queue and immediately return.

#### The HTTP Trigger hit by your web hook:

**function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous", // Don't do this - demonstration only.
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "queue",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "queue",
      "queueName": "process",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

**index.js**

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
  context.log('Started processing a request.', req);

  context.done(null, {
    res: { status: 202 },
    queue: { callbackUrl: req.body.callbackUrl, data: req.body.data }
  });
};
```

#### The Queue Trigger that does the processing:

**function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "item",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "process",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

**index.js**

```
module.exports = async function (context, item) {
    context.log('JavaScript queue trigger function started to process work item.', item);

    const data = await process(item.data);

    const request = require('request');

    await request.post(item.callbackUrl, { body: data, json: true });
};

function process(data) {
    // Some long running operation.
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve({ a: 'b', c: 'd' }), 5000);
    });
}
```

Note that I'm using `request` here, which is an external dependency you'll have to add to your `package.json`, but Node's built in HTTP Client will work just as well.